# Did RTools mess up my ability to run some packages?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rtools

I recently installed RTools (windows computer) and now it seems like all of my packages associated with `tidyverse` (e.g., `tidyverse` itself, `dplyr`, `ggplot2`, etc) no longer will load and can't be installed.

I get the following error when I load my R session:

```
Warning: namespace ‘ggplot2’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘ima.bar’
Warning: namespace ‘scales’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘a’
Warning: namespace ‘cowplot’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘rtp.dashboard’
```

Should I simply uninstall RTools and see if everything gets fixed? Or do I need to re-install R? The system environment (`Sys.getenv()`) also seems to have changed after installing RTools to something I'm not even sure of where it is (it isn't the folder where my packages are contained -- oddly, `tidyverse` does not even have a folder there either)>

Comment: RTools (by its installation or side-effect) does not impact any package installation or library path (`.libPaths()`). On my machine at least, it does not alter `PATH` or other environment variables; I rely on R (and `devtools`) to find and use it (I have it installed as `c:/Rtools/`, for a few reasons, not all sysadmins permit this). I wonder if things like your envvars changing are a symptom of some other change that you or your network admins have imposed. (Also, are you reloading `.Rdata` files in your projects? I avoid those like the plague.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to load .Rdata files. That has never happened until this morning (after installing RTools -- but that might be a coincidence). Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Note that there is a distinct difference between *"not trying to load .Rdata files"* and it actually happening. In RStudio, go to *"Tools > Global Options... > Workspace"* and verify if "Restore .RData into workspace at start" is selected (I believe it defaults to checked). (I'm assuming you are using RStudio.)

Comment: Yes, it is checked (and yes, I'm in RStudio). Oddly, when I even search for the ggplot2 or tidyverse package in RStudio, they don't come up?

Comment: Packages missing when you think they should be installed are almost always due to an issue with `.libPaths()`, I suggest you search for that trigger instead of RTools. On my win10 laptop, I have `"C:/Users/r2/R/win-library/3.5" "c:/R/R-3.5.3/library"`, so all packages that I install are loaded under my homedir. If you don't have that, or if it is pointing to a path you don't recognize, try adding your intended path to the set and see what happens.